# magento 2 admin unable to submitshipment

Tags: magento2, admin, submit-shipment

I have placed order created invoice and I am trying to create shipment but getting the error in console Can anyone pls help me?
[image]

Comment: add your jquery code on click function, add it on your post so that we can check what is the problem

Comment: default functionality i have n't added any jquery

Comment: you have no custom module that overrides the submit shipment?

Comment: how to find? override class